# cytoscapeJS snap to grid and guide lines that interact with other nodes

Tags: javascript, canvas, cytoscape.js

Can anyone help me out with adding span to grid and guideline functionality for CytoscapeJS ?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use an overlay for grid lines

(2) Listen to `free` events on nodes.  Move the node using `node.position()` to the closest grid line.